# Convert a part of data frame from factor to numeric

Tags: r, numeric

Current data frame (df)

```
      V1  V2  V3
 a    aa  0.11 1.11
 b    bb  3.45 2.24
 c    cc  2.23 3.45

sapply(df, class)

     V1    V2    V3 
 "factor" "factor" "factor"
```

I am trying to convert V2 and V3 to numeric 
and this is what I tried:

```
  df$V2<- as.numeric(df$V2)
  df$V3<- as.numeric(df$V3)
```

Then it became integers like 1 2 3.

I am wondering how can I convert factors to numeric form without changing the data

Comment: You must first use `as.character` llike `as.numeric(as.character(df$V2))`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df$V2<- as.numeric(as.character((df$V2))
df$V3<- as.numeric(as.character((df$V3))
```

I know there is a different way around this, but this usually works for me.